# How to delete all the content of a wordpress site without deleting the Post and pages?

Tags: posts, database

Is there any way to delete all the content of every post without actually deleting the post!

Suppose , I have articles

> 1. how to install wordpress ?
> 2. what is wordpress 
>      . . . . and so on
> 3. What is plugin ?

Suppose , I want to delete all the contents  of each article without actually deleting the post.

The title , the tag , the category should remain.  Only the  content should be deleted.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run this MySQL query to empty post content.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content='';
```

make sure you have a backup before you run this query, in case you need it later.
Also make sure that your MySQL table prefix is `wp_`.

### Another Method.

You can also use `WP_Query` custom query to remove post content.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
  'posts_per_page' => '-1',
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :
  while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

    wp_update_post( array(
      'ID'            => get_the_id(),
      'post_content'   => '',
    ) );

  endwhile;
endif;

wp_reset_postdata();
```

You can use any of the above method. Both are working, just tested them.

Comment: @pradip So did it work?